# Run iOS Simulator with 6.1.2

Tags: ios, cordova, ios-simulator, ios6.1

i have xCode 5.1.1 and need to test an app in iOS 6.1.2, because i have this issue only with 6.1.2 which is web related (cordova).

I normally use the iOS Simulator and run Safari in order to test it, but iOS Simulator does only offer 6.1 (10B141) but i need 6.1.2 (10B146). How can i get this version for the iOS Simulator? Is that actually possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If there is simulator v 6.1.2 it should show in

xcode->preferences->downloads

Comment: I m not sure, it might be latest version of 6.1. I'll not bet too much but Try downloading it might be 10B146

Comment: there is nothing to download, latest i can get and already have is 10B141